# Criteria, restrictions in subclasses with different pah

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, querying

I have a Superclass and then 2 subclases

```
Subclas1 extedns Superclas {
  otherClass OtherClass;
}
Subclas2 extedns Superclas {
  etcClass EtcClass;
}
EtcClass extends DoesntCare{
  otherClass OtherClass;
}
```

I want a Criteria over **Superclass**, but with a restriction even in `otherClass` or in `etcClass`
Some like:
//obvius alliases omitted here

.EQ("otherClass",otherClassVar) OR   .EQ("ectClass.otherClass",otherClassVar);**simultaneously**
Is this possible?

Comment: What?! Please post a working code example and clarify your question, what you really want to do!